# OpenCart VQmod Questions and Answers Module not showing

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I have installed Opencart 2.0.3.1.
vqmod 2.5.1.5 for Opencart,
vqmod manager 3.0,
and ProductQuestionsAndAnswers_v1.8.2_oc2.0.x.x

These have all been uploaded manually via ftp, i've followed the simple instructions for vqmod's installation to rewrite part of the index.php and admin/index.php which seems to have created all of the required cache files.

The module is installed, enabled and visible in the modules section and in the vqmod manager, however when I try adding the module to the theme layout there is no option for this module.

Everything appears to be working fine other than for not being able to insert the module into a layout.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the module's developer? If it's a paid module, then they should provide support (if you've purchased through opencart.com). If it's not, they would probably appreciate your efforts in reporting the bug (or in this case, incompatibility with the new Opencart version).

Comment: That is all fair. This is my first experience with Opencart and assumed there might be something simple missing in my set up rather than an incompatibility issue that prevents modules from displaying in the layout editor.

Answer (score 0):

Not all modules for Opencart have that option to add it in a layout.A big portion of the modules in opencart are made by students or people that are learning to code most of the free modules don't even have that option. Now that we have this out of the way.

Other solutions to this problem.

If you are using a custom /admin panel lets say your `admin` is called `bestbanana`

You need to open the VqMOD xml file that is located in the VQmod/xml folder
and change all the values that contain `admin` to `bestbanana`

Or if you are using a custom theme that has different structure than the default opencart one,than you need to modify it a little bit more.

Since VqMOD works as a search engine it searches/replaces adds and so forth bu it searches by exact words. e.g peaces of code.

but without posting any code or something similar there is nothing much that anyone can help you with.

Hope that this will help you

Comment: That's all good advice. It is a paid for module and so I have contacted the developer. The system is mostly default though, admin and theme. The only changes I have made to the entire system so far are installing the above modules.

Comment: I meant to add that. The reason I haven't been able to add any code is that I have no errors at all. Basically a client was given access to the website's admin and installed modules..etc and on that dev site i'm able to add the module to the layout, the problem they face is that it can be assigned to the theme but doesn't display on the site.

Comment: @TomFirth since vqmod's don't give a visible error they just get skipped if it's an error

Comment: that is odd,there has to be an issue somewhere,but without more information i am kinda helpless here